# nginx rewrite rule for using domain host to redirect to specific internal directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm new to Nginx rewrites and looking for help in getting a working and minimal rewrite code. We would like to use urls like 'somecity.domain.com' on campaign materials and have the result go to city-specific content within the 'www' site.

So, here are use cases, if the customer enters:

```
www.domain.com                          (stays) www.domain.com
domain.com                              (goes to) www.domain.com
www.domain.com/someuri                  (stays the same)
somecity.domain.com                     (no uri, goes to) www.domain.com/somecity/prelaunch
somecity.domain.com/landing             (goes to)   www.domain.com/somecity/prelaunch
somecity.domain.com/anyotheruri         (goes to) www.domain.com/anyotheruri
```

Here's what I've come up with so far, and it partially works.  What I can't understand is how to check if there is no path/uri after the host, and I'm guessing there is probably a way better way to do this.

```
if ($host ~* ^(.*?)\.domain\.com)
{   set $city $1;}
if ($city ~* www)
{   break; }
if ($city !~* www)
{ 
  rewrite ^/landing http://www.domain.com/$city/prelaunch/$args permanent;
  rewrite (.*) http://www.domain.com$uri$args permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is best accomplished using three servers:

```
# www.domain.com, actually serves content
server {
  server_name www.domain.com;
  root /doc/root;

  # locations, etc
}

# redirect domain.com -> www.domain.com
server {
  server_name domain.com;
  rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

# handle anything.domain.com that wasn't handled by the above servers
server {
  # ~ means regex server name
  # 0.8.25+
  #server_name ~(?<city>.*)\.domain\.com$;

  # < 0.8.25
  server_name ~(.*)\.domain\.com$;
  set $city $1;

  location = / { rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/$city/prelaunch; }
  location = /landing { rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/$city/prelaunch; }
  # should there be a /$city before $request_uri?
  location / { rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com$request_uri?; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.  Our cloud host is on nginx 0.7.65, however, so the references to '$city' is unrecognized.  Is there a way to keep the definitions in the server defs like your example, but add a variable in a way the back release supports?

Comment: I edited the config to show how you would set $city pre-0.8.25